# Why a TextView's "layout_width" property can determine whether accessing UI components from background threads will succeed?

Tags: android, multithreading

I've learned that it is not allowed to access UI components in background threads, but what I've encountered made me confused. I did the following.

(1) I created a new Android Studio project with package name `com.example.myapplication` and minimum SDK version 29, using "Empty Activity" template.

(2) I changed `activity_main.xml`, adding a button and a TextView, where the `android:layout_width` of the TextView was set to `wrap_content`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

(3) I changed `MainActivity.kt`, adding a click listener to the button, which starts a thread and changes the text of the TextView in the thread.

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)

        button.setOnClickListener {
            thread {
                textView.text = "Accessing textView from ${Thread.currentThread().name}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(4) I launched the app in an API 31 emulator, and clicked the button. The app crashed with the following error:

```
2022-03-29 23:48:42.364 24327-24360/com.example.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 24327
    android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

This is the expected behavior. But when I changed the `android:layout_width` property of the TextView to `match_parent` (or a fixed width, like `100dp`), rebuilt and started the app, and clicked the button again, the text of the TextView was successfully changed.
The thread name indicated that I was definitely accessing the TextView from a background thread.

[image]

Why does this happen? Why a TextView's `layout_width` property can determine whether accessing UI components from background threads will succeed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely access the UI Thread from a background thread.

You should note that the `ViewGroup` (`LinearLayout`) that holds the TextView is responsible for it's width and height if you set it as `match_parent`.

So that means that every dynamic changes to the width or height of the `TextView` at runtime **MUST** run on the UI Thread not from a background thread. That explains this exception

```
2022-03-29 23:48:42.364 24327-24360/com.example.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2
Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 24327
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

The keynote in the above Exception is:

> Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views

Since it was the UI Thread that created the `ViewGroup` (`LinearLayout`), only the UI Thread is permitted to run layout changes on the `ViewGroup` and it's children Views.

Now the reason the Exception was resolved when you gave the `android:layout_width` a finite value such as `100dp` is because the finite value means there won't be any dynamic layout changes for the UI Thread (which created the `ViewGroup`) to be worried about.

The only change you are going to make at runtime is the value shown in the `TextView` and this would not change it's layout structure (since you've set the `android:layout_width` with a finite `100dp` and the `android:layout_height` is at `wrap_content`).

The only time you should be worried about the `android:layout_height` is when you change the font size or `TextView`'s height dynamically **in another thread** which is not the UI Thread.

Now to access the UI Thread in another thread. Do this:

```
button.setOnClickListener {
        thread {
           runOnUiThread {
            textView.text = "Accessing textView from ${Thread.currentThread().name}"
           }
        }
    }
```

The above snippet accesses the UI Thread from the background thread.

I hope this helps.

Comment: With the help of your answer I've finally figured out the reason. The app will crash only if changing the text of the TextView causes changes in the TextView's rendered width or height. Thanks!